# How do I move-append one std::vector to another?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector, move-semantics

Suppose I have an `std::vector<T> from` and `std::vector<T> to` where `T` is a non-copyable but moveable type and `to` may or may not be empty. I want all elements in `from` to be appended after `to`.

If I use the [`std::vector<T>::insert(const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) overload (4) with `pos = to.end()`, it will attempt to **copy** all objects.

Now, if `to.empty()` I could just `std::move(from)` and otherwise I could first `from.reserve(from.size()+to.size())` and then manually `to.emplace_back(std::move(from[i]))` every element of `from` and finally `from.clear()`.

Is there a direct way of doing this with an `std` convenience function or wrapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`insert` will work fine with [std::move_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) and [std::make_move_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) helper fucntion:

```
to.insert(to.end(),std::make_move_iterator(from.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(from.end()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iterator>

std::vector<T> source = {...};

std::vector<T> destination;

std::move(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(destination));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider the [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) *algorithm* – i.e., the moving counterpart of [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) – instead of the [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) convenience template function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct OnlyMovable {
   OnlyMovable() = default;
   OnlyMovable(const OnlyMovable&) = delete;
   OnlyMovable(OnlyMovable&&) = default;
};

auto main() -> int {
   std::vector<OnlyMovable> from(5), to(3);
   std::move(from.begin(), from.end(), std::back_inserter(to)); 
}
```

Comment: Somehow I always forget about `<algorithm> std::move`. This doesn't take care of fulling moving the **vector** (as opposed to its elements) but I guess I just have to write a small wrapper.